# Flutter M1 Mac ld: framework not found google_sign_in

Tags: flutter, dart, google-signin, apple-silicon

I was getting this error below on an m1 Mac

```
1 warning generated.
ld: framework not found google_sign_in
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
note: Using new build system
note: Planning
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in dependency order
```

==== Solved ====

What I had to do is go to

Xcode => Runner => Build settings => Under linking => Double click "Other linker flags"

Delete these two

```
-framework
"google_sign_in"
```

> Only the framework before the "google_sign_in"

Had the same problem with `image_picker` also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I had to do is go to

Xcode => Runner => Build settings => Under linking => Double click "Other linker flags"

Delete these two

```
-framework
"google_sign_in"
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be also breaking naming change. After fighting with `Pod` setup I have checked that in my `.symlinks/plugins` I have **different** pod downloaded!
It was `google_sign_in_ios` not `google_sign_in`. Renaming it to the downloaded one helped me.